# Decoding a base64 line of string using Python

Tags: base64, decode, base64url

I'm trying to decode the following string text, as there is a message hidden in it:

```
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
```

I have the following code:

```
Message = "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"

#Message is a string#

str_original = Message
type (Message)
bytes_encoded = str_original.encode(encoding='utf-8')
print(type(bytes_encoded))

str_decoded = bytes_encoded.decode()
print(type(str_decoded))

#rint('Encoded bytes =', bytes_encoded)
#rint('Decoded String =', str_decoded)
#rint('str_original equals str_decoded =', str_original == str_decoded)

def decode(s: str, encoding="utf-8")-> str:
    encoded = Message.encode(encoding)
    b64_decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded + b"===")
    return b64_decoded.decode(encoding)

decode(str_original)

Base64_encoded(str_decoded)
```

but am getting the following error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The base64 string contains binary data, probably a 7-zip file.